# Where did Mysteries In History get the story about Zartha?

Tags: men-in-black-2

One of the clues that Agent K left behind to remind him about Zartha was an episode of the show *Mysteries in History* where Peter Graves recounts in very accurate detail the story of Zartha and the Men In Black.

Is there a specific reason why they knew about that story, let alone had the ability to publish it on television and video?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jay's impression is that **the episode was made by** (or at least with the assistance of) **the MIB themselves** in order to help to discredit anyone who learns of their existence and tries to go public.

> *Jay watched marveling at the beauty of it all. It was Edgar Allan
> Poe's gambit from "The Purloined Letter": There's no better place to
> hide than in plain sight. **Make a videotape that reveals the truth
> about the Men in Black, but make it to look like the lowest of
> low-budget sci-fi featurettes, and no one would ever believe it,**
> except for the eccentrics, cranks, nut cases, and "woo-woos."*
>
> <sub><sup>[MIB:2 - Official Novelisation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345450663)</sup></sub>

Given that the episode happens to be about the Light of Zartha, it doesn't take a leap of the imagination to work out that Kay was the one assigned to the task of creating this episode and realised that he could (ab)use this opportunity to set up a story that would jog his memory one day.

Comment: Made me think of this; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole_X-Treme!